# Sign-in using Azure AD auth failed

Tags: gitlab, azure-active-directory

When I try to access Gitlab via Azure AD, i am getting the following error. Could someone point me where is the issue?

```
Sign-in using Azure AD auth failed
Email has already been taken
```

I tried to recover password, but didn't receive any email sent to my email.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the problem persists.
There were:

- [`gitlab-com/gl-infra/production` issue 15997](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/15997): "2023-07-07: Site-wide outage"
- [`gitlab-com/gl-infra/production` issue 15999](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/production/-/issues/15999): "Incident Review for Site-wide Outage for GitLab.com"

The incident you mentioned resulted in users seeing a 503 error when trying to access any page on gitlab.com, along with some users seeing an incomplete list of commits.

If you only had issues with Azure AD sign-in but were able to access other parts of gitlab.com without problems, it is likely that your issue is not directly related to this incident.

---

The reason you might not have received the password recovery email could be that this existing account is not linked to Azure AD. Or it could be linked to a different authentication provider. In addition, email could be sent to spam or the email service could be blocking it.

Make sure the recovery emails may end up in your spam or junk folder.
And that you are using the correct email that's associated with your GitLab account.

Check also if the email address you are using to sign in through Azure AD matches with the email in your GitLab account.

If you are part of an organization, your Azure AD administrator might have more visibility into what's going wrong and be able to resolve the issue.
If the account exists but is not linked to Azure AD, you or your administrator can link the existing account to Azure AD.

Comment: I did aware of that Gitlab issue, but that's not the issue for me. My issue is related to AzureAD

Comment: @Stella I agree. I just mentioned it in case there was some weird side-effect.

Comment: Sure, Appreciate that!

Comment: @Stella I have edited the answer to add some checks to follow.